# handle linux terminal application with java

Tags: java, linux, bash, opensuse

I want to create a java program for handling a linux terminal application (sipp).

I can start this application with bash this way:

```
proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash", null, wd);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
       OutputStream outputStream = proc.getOutputStream();
       OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream());
       BufferedWriter buffered = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);
       PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(buffered, true);
       printWriter.println("cd ../***/sipp/sipp-3.3/");
       printWriter.println("./sipp -i "+Config.IP+" -sf uac.xml "+Config.IP+":5060");
```

As default the sipp script sends 10 calls per second to the server. If you start this application within a terminal you can use '/' '*' '-' '+' to increase or decrease the calls per second.

Now I want to have 50 calls per second, so I have to type * four times. But if I use

```
 printWriter.println("*");
```

the terminal stops working and is waiting for command to close.

So I tried to send the * character with the output stream:

```
           outputStream.write("*".getBytes());
       outputStream.write("*".getBytes());
       outputStream.write("*".getBytes());
       outputStream.write("*".getBytes());
       outputStream.flush();
```

After I flushed these commands, I can see the increased number of calls per second in the output. But the terminal stops working again, after the flush command ended.

I think there is anything wrong with the linebreak, because when I send a

```
 printWriter.print("*");
```

command, nothing happens.

Maybe it is important to know, that sipp updates the terminal every second and that it is only allowed to type in p q / * - + and 1-9 and that you can't see your input and that your input will be executed directly.

I hope somebody can help me!
Many Thanks!

Comment: Are you really using `outputStream.write("*".getBytes());` instead of `outputStream.write('*');`? Anyway, do you also *read* from the other streams?

Comment: Yes i am using, `outputStream.write("*".getBytes());`
within another thread i am reading from the input stream all the time.

Comment: I still don’t get your problem description: “*After I flushed* these commands, I can see the increased number of calls per second in the output. But the terminal stops working again, *after the flush command* ended.” So *when* do you see the desired effect and *when* does the terminal stop working? Both at the same time?

Comment: The other thread prints all the time there is any income from the BufferedReader to my console. In the console I can see that the call rate is 10 calls per second on the next print it is 20 calls per second... till it is 50 calls per second. Then the terminal stops working completly. Then I get some empty rows from the server and that's it. So I think the terminal stops when i call `outputStream.flush();` It is also very strange that on every print the total time is 0.00 seconds and no call is going to the server.
When i don't send any command it is working fine with 10 calls per second.

Comment: This makes no sense, without a `flush` no data will be transmitted at all. At the time you receive an acknowledging input, the flush has been processed completely. It’s rather that the problem is caused by what you do *after* the flush. It’s also possible that your reading code is broken.

Comment: After the `flush` I just do a `Thread.sleep(10000);` for this thread.
I don't think that anything goes wrong with the reading code, because if i don't `flush` everything is correct and the reading thread don't do anything else than `line = in.readLine();` and `System.out.println(line);` within a while loop.

Comment: It seems, that the terminal freezes, when he gets the `flush` command, because when I start the application and let it sleep for 10 seconds, at all printouts i have got a total time of 9.97 seconds and after the terminal received the last update (* from 40 to 50 calls per seconds) nothing happens anymore and don't get any new output. Usually I should get an output every second, because sipp updates every second the total time.

Comment: The terminal does not receive a `flush` command. The `flush` is an all-Java-internal thing which just causes buffered bytes to be written. All the outside world will see are just the four stars (bytes) transferred. There’s nothing in the code you have shown which can explain a freeze. Well, besides the fact that I don’t see an attempt to read the *error stream*. Since you said your are reading *the* input stream (singular) I suppose you fix that first.

Comment: Ok, I implemented another thread for the error stream, but there is no output from this stream.

Comment: Then there’s not much to draw from the given information. You may post more code or do more tests. What happen’s if you send five `'*'` or just three before flushing, other commands, etc…

Comment: hmmm, there is not much more code to, there are just some `Thread.sleep` methods and at the end there are `stop` and `close` methods. And i also tried to send `'*'` ot to send `"****".getBytes()` but its always the same. I also tried, to pause the traffic with `p` or just to quit (`q`) the program. These commands all are working, but the terminal don't do anything, after the last comment is executed. As i said it seems that it is freezed or maybe waiting for anything to go on.

Comment: Maybe that’s the problem: what do you expect the terminal to do? Especially after sending the quit command?

Comment: usually the terminal should go on with the process and send as many calls per second as I set. 
Ok the terminal should not do that if I send `q` to sipp, but after i sent `q` sipp normally should printout an overview of the last session with some statistics like average calls per seconds... And then the terminal should be ready for another command like `cd` ...

Comment: Now i get a warning when i am starting sipp `Warning: open file limit > FD_SETSIZE; limiting max. # of open files to FD_SETSIZE = 1024` anybody know what that means and how to fix it?

Comment: I have a vague idea but I think you’re better off opening a new question which is not tagged with [java] for it.